# Exporting data from a website

Tags: web-scraping, web, data-mining

I would like to make an application that will export some data, that I will choose, from a website like Google books (such as the tags of each book). Can you tell me which is the best or preferred language to do so, and how to start? Show me some tutorials books and a path to start with...

Answer (score 0):

depends on the website. Large-scale data crawling is usually discouraged as it inflicts an unnecessary amount of server load and traffic on the website. However, many you'll often find some website providing an API for communicating directly with the data base.

So, check the website and try to find if they provide some kind of data API that is written in a programming language that you can use. Then write a small program that uses the API to extract the data needed.